# Cooking diary and recipe app which allows multiple pictures

Tags: android, calendar, planning, cooking

I am looking for an application for Android which will let you store your own recipes and store multiple pictures per recipe along with the recipe text.

The application should also allow you to asssign recipes to calendar meal events such as "breakfast", "lunch", "snack", and "supper" for each calendar day. The calendar should include a diary of meals and a meal plan for the future meals. Optionally a list of ingredients should be stored for each meal item.

Ideally I would have liked an app that supported an unlimited number of pictures per recipe so that I could also include all the pics for all the steps for each recipe, but to my knowledge no such app exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[My Cookbook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.cookbook)** and am very satisfied with it. It seems to meet your requirements, as far as I understand:

- **let you store your own recipes:** Yes.
- **store multiple pictures per recipe:** Yes (see 3<sup>rd</sup> screenshot below).
- **assign recipes to calendar meal events such as "breakfast":** Can be done using the app's category system.
- **for each calendar day:** There's a [Meal Planer](http://mycookbook-android.com/site/meal-planner/) feature for that, but it requires an account with the website. The free account has some limitations (e.g. amount of recipes), but should be usable.<sup>**1**</sup>
- **Optionally a list of ingredients should be stored for each meal item:** For each recipe, yes. The app even generates a shopping list if you want.

You didn't ask for, but I still include: Import recipes you've found on the net. It can directly import from many recipe sites if you simply provide it the URL of the recipe you wish to import.

[image: Overview] [image: Directions] [image: Details]
<sup>*My Cookbook:* Recipe overview, directions, details (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.cookbook); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I chose the "smartphone screenshots" here to give you an idea. Of course the app also supports tablets with a corresponding layout, which is how I use it (on a 9" tablet). Check out the linked Playstore page for more screenshots.

I use this app for quite a while now, and am really satisfied. A special little thing is that it disables keyguard when you've got a recipe open, so the screen doesn't switch off while you're cooking.

For alternatives, be welcome checking with my app list to [Manage your own recipes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_food_recipes#group_975) :)

---

<sup>**1:** Note that I've never used this feature, so I cannot tell how good it works</sup>

Comment: Thanks Izzy, the problem I'm having is that I don't want to eat the same thing every day, so I need this to also be a meal diary so I can make sure looking back that I am having an enough diversified diet that I don't run into health problems by not getting enough of one dish. And would like to be able to click on recipe entries to plan ahead but also to assign them top actual things I ate when these clash with the meal plan. Entering recipes is fine but I can never remember what I ate and cannot ensure I'm not always eating the same thing. Thanks. (maybe someone still needs to write an app li

Comment: Being home again and in reach of that tablet, I've just checked: there's a [Meal Planer](http://mycookbook-android.com/site/meal-planner/) feature I've never used, as it requires an online account. Checking the linked documentation, that's exactly what you were asking for!

Comment: Does the meal planner feature include the ability to assign to both past and future calendar meals?

Comment: As I've never used it, I can only refer you to the documentation (or the support) for that, sorry. Docs don't say anything about "only for future events", so I'd *assume* assigning recipes to past events should work as well. I've just checked if one could instead simply "share" it with the devices calendar – but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case (calendar doesn't show in available targets). Might be depending on apps available, so you could try that (the app is free, so nothing to lose :)

Comment: do you know whether the pictures are store on the server? I ask because I'm running out off space on my device. If so, then are the image files shrunken once they're uploaded to the server (or is it possible to download them back in their original size once they're uploaded to the my cookbook server?) Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington as I wrote, I never used the online features, not even created an account there. So in my case, the pics must be local :)

Comment: Ok, I will just got the pro version. I will create an online account and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, at 20$ per year, subscription greed for this app are write pricey.

Comment: Feedback is welcome then, @JackMaddington :)

Comment: Trying to figure out if I can use the Dropbox feature instead.

Comment: the app sucks because I can only store 7 dish pictures per recipe and i I'm after an unlimited amount so I can take pictures of all the steps. Could you please suggest another app?

Comment: In your question you just wrote "multiple", not "unlimited". For me 1 pic per recipe is enough, so I've never checked for that feature. And no: That's the only recipe manager I've tried. Was satisfied with it, so I didn't check further. Be welcome to check my app list [Manage your own recipes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_food_recipes#group_975) for other candidates.

Comment: Actually I've just discovered that the number of pics power recipe is unlimited with the My Cookbook app. All you have to do is save and edit again to be given the option of adding more pics two more at a time. So it meets the requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, cool – good to know, so thanks for pointing out!